# Can't run a MapReduce job with YARN

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm making my first steps mastering hadoop. I've setup a CDH4.5 in distributed mode (on two virtual machines). I'm having problems running MapReduce jobs with YARN. I could launch successfully a DistributedShell application (from CDH examples), but once I run a MapReduce job, it just hangs there forever.

This is what I'm trying to launch:

```
sudo -uhdfs yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi 1 1
```

These are the last resource manager's log lines:

```
13/12/10 23:30:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1386714123362_0001
13/12/10 23:30:02 INFO client.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1386714123362_0001 to ResourceManager at master/192.168.122.175:8032
13/12/10 23:30:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1386714123362_0001/
13/12/10 23:30:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1386714123362_0001
```

The node manager's log doesn't get any new messages once I run the job.

This is what I see on resource manager's web page regarding the job:

```
State - ACCEPTED
FinalStatus - UNDEFINED
Progress - (progress bar in 0%) 
Tracking UI - UNASSIGNED

Apps Submitted - 1
Apps Pending - 1 
Apps Running - 0
```

Comment: What kind of services are running in the hosts? For me JobHistory was missing on master

Comment: try runnig pi program with this parameters instead of 1 1 : 16 1000. nothing changed?

Answer (score 0):

I found this at http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.6-alpha/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/releasenotes.html:

YARN-300. Major bug reported by shenhong and fixed by Sandy Ryza (resourcemanager , scheduler)
After YARN-271, fair scheduler can infinite loop and not schedule any application.
After yarn-271, when yarn.scheduler.fair.max.assign<=0, when a node was been reserved, fairScheduler will infinite loop and not schedule any application.

try with new version i.e. 2.0 above

Answer (score 0):

Probably caused by system resource issue, I fixed it by restarting my system.